Finding Expectation of a Uniform random variable from its moment generating function
From Taylor series, if I need to get the k-th moment, I need to find the k-th derivative of the Moment Generating function.
If I have $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$, the MGF $M_{X}(s)$ is; $$M_{X}(s) = \frac{e^{s} - 1}{s} \quad \text{and} \quad E[X^k] = \left. \frac{d^k}{ds^k} M_{X}(s) \right|_{s=0}$$
If I use the derivative above to compute mean, $E[X]$, I get the undefined since the derivative becomes a divide by zero. Is there any technique I can use to arrive at $E[X]=\frac{1}{2}$?

The moment generating function is actually given by $M_X(s)=\dfrac{e^s-1}{s}$ if $s\neq 0$ and $M_X(0)=1$.
We can use the definition of derivative at $s=0$. Indeed, we find $$\dfrac{M_X(s)-M_X(0)}{s}=\dfrac{\dfrac{e^s-1}{s}-1}{s}=\dfrac{e^s-1-s}{s^2}$$
We can apply L'Hôpital's Rule or the exponential's Taylor series. Using the latter, we find $$\dfrac{e^s-1-s}{s^2}=\dfrac{1+s+s^2/2+O(s^3)-1-s}{s^2}=\dfrac{s^2/2+O(s^3)}{s^2}\to \dfrac{1}{2},$$
as desired.
